# How to customize the pie chart background in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am doing a powerpoint slide something like this:

[image]

It's very nice that the chart extents different parts into its own background with a similar color.

How can I do this automatically in powerpoint?

I mean I can add a pie chart in powerpoint, but then what? I have different pie charts, then design a background for each chart will be time-consuming.

[image]

This is a strange question, thank you.

Answer (score 11):

**You can! If you cheat a little...**

You can make a copy of the chart and enlarge it so it covers all the slide. Then you can change de colors of the copy, to make it more lighter.
The trick it's to center both charts so they have the same center point. I have made a sample to show what I mean....
[image: A sample of how it's done]

Comment: I never thought of this for an infographic in 8 years as an Analyst providing these. +1, and welcome to GD.SE.

Answer (score 6):

### You can't.

This is —most probably— not an automated effect, this graphic has been designed by hand.

In order to find the similar colours, you'd need to dive into colour theory and find out about the HSB / HSV colour model to make lighter shades of a given colour. To make the actual background shapes, you'd have to make those manually in PowerPoint or a vector-oriented design app like Illustrator or Inkscape. The embossing effect on the actual pie chart is most probably added with a similar app or with Photoshop.

Be aware that lots of cool things are just filters and automated effects, but lots of them also are *not* and they just require time, time, creativity and then more time.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a single click job. The result resembles something which can be made in general purpose graphic programs with a little more than doing something most trivial. In Powerpoint that's reflected as numerous formatting selections. In this case you must make the right **Bevel** selections. The rectangular shapes have also shadows. And, of course, every item must be inserted.

The underlying sector extension can be made by stretching a copy of the chart (no effets, washed colors) to a big size.  I guess the extension is a manual drawing, because there's a rectangle insertion to the magenta sector. Actually a half of the extensions only must be exact drawings with black stroke edges.The rest are hidden below.

Bevel effects for extruded 3D appearance of shapes and chart parts have been available at least twelve years.

**Not asked:** That slide is a mess. Consider to make a simple main structure overview and present the sector details separately. Of course it's different, if you can highlight and zoom out selected details at a time, but then it's not any more the shown image as is.

Comment: +1 just for the part "that slide is a mess".

Answer (score 0):

Nice question! You can easily add the pie chart in PowerPoint using “Insert Chart” option. 
A pie chart has appeared. 
1.  Right-click the object.
2.  Choose Group and then ungroup.
3.  Click beside the object and drag the arrow over it.
4.  Select the shape to change the color and Right click the object( click any object which you want to change color)
5.  Choose Format Shape in the dialog box.
6.  Choose “Fill” in the Format Shape box then “Solid” or “Gradient” depending on the appearance of the object. Change color as shown in the picture.
7.  Select the shape to change the color 
8.  Go to Design Tab – Variants - Colors
9.  Choose any theme color “Built-In” depending on the appearance of the object.

Through the above steps, you can easily customize the pie-chart background. I have found a website on Google It's www[dot]slideteam[dot]net. Here, you can more tutorials of PowerPoint.